# main.CRITICAL: Block order_create_billing_form throws exception and cannot be rendered. - Where is this logged?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, payment-methods, logging

Can anyone please enlighten me where I can find this exception logged?

> main.CRITICAL: Block order_create_billing_form throws exception and
>   cannot be rendered. [] []

The context is a custom payment gateway, which works 100% in front.

But, when I try and use it from admin, placing order via admin, I get the noted error logged in system.log, and that is about it.

So, I am told there is an exception, but not what it is....

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Custom payment method came from third party extenson ?

Comment: No. I am creating it. My code.

Comment: Developer / default / production mode ?

Comment: I forgot to place this vagrant instance into developer mode!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

So I forgot to place this box in developer mode.
Once that was done, I got my error.

It was simply an undefined (typo) variable in code.
Easy once I could get the error: lesson learned: check the mode!